# how to intercept key event of swift iOS app?

Tags: swift, events, key, uikeycommand

I deleted the `@UIApplicationMain` in `AppDelegate.swift`and wrote the `main.swift` as below , but the program still can not fire `keyPressed` function. But executes `print("send event2")` every keydown.

How to fire `keyPressed` function? Is something wrong with this program?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class TApplication: UIApplication {
    override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent!) {
       super.sendEvent(event)
    }

    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
      print("send event2") // this is an example
        return [
            UIKeyCommand(input: "1", modifierFlags: [], action: Selector(("keyPressed:")), discoverabilityTitle: “1”),
            UIKeyCommand(input: "2", modifierFlags: .shift, action: Selector("keyPressed:"), discoverabilityTitle: “2”)]
        ]
    }

    func keyPressed(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
        print("keypressed event !!!!!!!!") // this is an example
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i  modify  'selector'  to be  #selector  （swift 3）  and finally solved  the problem,  maybe there was a bug

Comment: "  action:  #selector(keyPressed(sender:))  "  instead of  "action: Selector(("keyPressed:"))"

Comment: You can even omit the paramter definition like this `#selector(keyPressed)` but make sure to add `@objc` before `func keyPressed(sender: UIKeyCommand { // ... }`